# Upgrade the Titanium SDK Version for a Project

Tags: sdk, version, titanium, upgrade, appcelerator

I'm having a Titanium project build on `sdk version 6.x` and I want to upgrade to `sdk version 9`, but I'm having many issues and conflicts. Is there any way or a documentation to do the upgrade without getting into those issues?

Comment: there is not a general guide since you left out 7 (Dec 2017) and 8 (March 2019) already. If you use any module they have to be updated first. You can have a look at the Release notes and the error messages. That will give you a clue what to do. If you have any special errors please post them here or join the TiSlack

Comment: thanks a lot, it was really helpfull

Comment: again, if you have other errors or problems feel free to add a new more specific post and we'll get the error solved! Updating from 8 -> 9 is normally a quick and easy task. 6 -> 9 might need some code changes depending on your project and structure. But not impossible to do! Good luck